# print button in Crystal report viewer not working

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Repot 9 and VB6.0. I can display the report through Crystal report viewer properly. But the print button in the Crystal report viewer does not work. My printer is in network. If I print any other file such as .doc, .txt then the printer prints the file. But when I click the print button in the Crystal report viewer then it neither prints the report nor through any error message. Where is the problem? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

These thoughts come to mind:

1. Have you tried this more than 1 report? Maybe the file itself has a problem.
2. Can you get your IT to hook up a printer directly to your machine for about 5 minutes? (Yes, I know that is much harder to **do** than to **say**).
   If it prints, then perhaps crystal has a problem with the printer network.
3. Try exporting your crystal file to PDF first, then print that.
4. You say that you're using VB6.  Are you controlling Crystal thru automation in any way when printing this?
5. This might be better handled at [ServerFault.com](http://ServerFault.com) (see links below). It's a sister site to this one that has the same interface.